# iPhone app rejected due to background location mode

Tags: iphone, background, geolocation, app-store

I needed to use location in background mode so that I can track if the user has entered into a region or not. But my app was rejected with the following message:

> Additionally, we found that your app uses a background mode but does not include 
>   functionality that requires that mode to run persistently. This behavior is not
>   in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> We noticed your app declares support for location in the `UIBackgroundModes` key in your `Info.plist` but does not include features that require persistent location.
>
> It would be appropriate to add features that require location updates while the app is in the background or remove the "location" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.

Can anybody help me out; am I missing something?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: I guess it is pretty much clear, please suggest me what kind of info may i upload

Comment: Did you read the email message?

Comment: Did you manage to get it approved? What was the actual reason or what did you do to get it approved?

Comment: it is very clear what he is asking here. This is a pretty simple and straight forward question. Here is the simple and straightforward answer:

you don't need the location background mode for region monitoring. If you enter or exit a region (assuming you've set triggers for both), the app will be launched in the background with the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey launch option.

Answer (score 4):

Is location tracking necessary for the described functionality of your app?

Did you clearly describe the location tracking feature in your app's description?

Did you test your app to make sure that Location services actually still runs without quiting and without errors when your app is in background mode for an extended period of time?

If this functionality needs to be enabled by the user, did you explain how to do so in the review notes?

ADDED:

Can a user in Cupertino tell by the app's behavior that Location services was running in the background?

Comment: Thanks for the answer...Please find my answers to your reply...Yes location tracking is necessary for the described functionality of the app...I did not clearly describe it in the description...Yes I did test it and there were no errors...This functionality is not to be enabled by the user, it is automatically provided by the app..

Comment: Then change your app's description to make obvious the background use of location tracking in your app.  Have someone proof read the description to make sure it's absolutely clear.  Check the links in your rejection email for what to do next.

Comment: I guess not..if a user is in cupertino we wont be using GPS..

Answer (score 0):

"I needed to use location in background mode so that I can track if the user has entered into a region or not."

From the rejection, either Apple didn't accept your view that you needed this functionality (i.e. it was unnecessary for the functioning of your app), or that you had failed to actually implement this. I wonder if it is the latter. If your app does nothing with the background notifications of location change, and would have operated exactly the same if it just got a location update when it is re-launched, then it does not need to be running in the background. Could that be the issue?

Comment: no it is not the issue...I need to run the location services in background to check if the user enters a regions or not and then subsequently notifying him about this...how can I do this without using location in background??